# How to get the path to a FieldField considering the upload_to() function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, imagefield, filefield

I am making an app with Django and I am working with an ImageField. I have this function as the upload_to argument:

```
def group_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/group_<id>/time/<filename>
    return 'Groups/group_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.id, get_time(), filename)
```

However, I want to resize the group image, so I need to access the group.photo ImageField FieldFile. My problem is that when try to get the FieldFile path with group.photo.path, I get

> /media/429760_490645240984035_288529563_n.JPG

but I there is no file in this directory, because the file is in

> /media/Groups/group_2/2-3-2019-23-54/429760_490645240984035_288529563_n.JPG

instead. How do I get the right file path?

Comment: Please post more code, like model and usage in view.

Comment: @DavidePizzolato finally, I had to change my media-url in settings.py

Comment: Please post the answer and set it as solution